# sub menu pushing content to right side

Tags: css

CSS code supposes to display sub-menu relatively and not pushing other contents to right side. Sub-menu2 displays its contents correctly but when the mouse palces on the header it displays but it pushes the next header. what is wrong here and how to solve it?

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About Company</a></li>
                    <li id="businessU">
                        <a href="#">Business Units</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Solution Engineering Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution Bioforce Sdn Bhd </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution Biogen Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution A&C Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution E&E Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Investor">
                        <a href="#">Investor Relations</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu2">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Directors">Directors</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/CorporateStructure">Corporate Structure </a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/News">News</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Events">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Anno">Announcements</a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
```

CSS

```
/* sub menu1 display*/

.nav .sub-menu {      
     position:relative;
     display:none;

}

#businessU:hover .sub-menu {
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:2px;
float:right;

}
 /* sub menu1 display end*/

/* sub menu2 display*/

.nav .sub-menu2 {      
     position:relative;
     display:none;

}

#Investor:hover .sub-menu2 {
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:2px;
float:left;

}
/* sub menu2 display end*/
```

[image]

Comment: You've defined `ul {` twice, once with `float: right;` and once with `float: left;`

Comment: Both menus have the same effect, the push the parent to the right-hand side. What it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: already changed it to left but still have the same problem.. look to the attached picture who the business header pushed investor header when sub menu displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: relative` does not remove an element from the document flow.  `position: absolute` does.  If you change your `.submenu` and `.submenu2` (which you could technically combine into one class) from `position: relative` to `position: absolute` and add in `position: relative` to your `.nav.navbar` and the submenus drop nicely without interfering with anything else.

```css
/* sub menu1 display*/

.nav .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#businessU:hover .sub-menu {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
}
/* sub menu1 display end*/
/* sub menu2 display*/

.nav .sub-menu2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#Investor:hover .sub-menu2 {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}
/* sub menu2 display end*/

.nav.navbar-nav {
  position: relative;
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About Company</a></li>
    <li id="businessU">
      <a href="#">Business Units</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Solution Engineering Sdn Bhd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution Bioforce Sdn Bhd </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution Biogen Sdn Bhd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution A&C Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution E&E Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="Investor">
      <a href="#">Investor Relations</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu2">
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Directors">Directors</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/CorporateStructure">Corporate Structure </a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/News">News</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Events">Events</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Anno">Announcements</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The error was in position relative and when I changed it (according to you answer )  to absolute it works.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? Changed `position: relative` to `position: fixed` for your submenus.

```css
/* sub menu1 display*/

.nav .sub-menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
#businessU:hover .sub-menu {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  float: right;
}
/* sub menu1 display end*/

/* sub menu2 display*/

.nav .sub-menu2 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
#Investor:hover .sub-menu2 {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
}
/* sub menu2 display end*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About Company</a>

    </li>
    <li id="businessU"> <a href="#">Business Units</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Solution Engineering Sdn Bhd</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution Bioforce Sdn Bhd </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution Biogen Sdn Bhd</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution A&C Technology Sdn Bhd</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution E&E Technology Sdn Bhd</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="Investor"> <a href="#">Investor Relations</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu2">
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Directors">Directors</a>

        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/CorporateStructure">Corporate Structure </a>

        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/News">News</a>

        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Events">Events</a>

        </li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Anno">Announcements</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact Us</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, all you need to do is adjust it to your classes and IDs:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ul ul {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About Company</a></li>
                    <li id="businessU">
                        <a href="#">Business Units</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Solution Engineering Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution Bioforce Sdn Bhd </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution Biogen Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution A&C Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Solution E&E Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Investor">
                        <a href="#">Investor Relations</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu2">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Directors">Directors</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/CorporateStructure">Corporate Structure </a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/News">News</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Events">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Anno">Announcements</a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: you see Business Units, I do not want it to push Investor to right when the Business Units sub menu display